# jQuery custom accordion, couldn't make it collapsible

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I have a custom accordion, like jQuery UI accordion. I am also trying to make any expanded item collapsible (if it is clicked again).  Something like this: https://jqueryui.com/accordion/#collapsible 
But I am unable to figure out how to capture another click event on the currently expanded item. Can someone point me to the right direction?

```
    <div class="dropdown">
        <div class="style1 dropdown-link" style='background-color: rgb(75, 78, 80);'>Timecard Error Message</div>
        <div class="style2 dropdown-container" style="display: none">
            <div class="ExternalClassA37E015771DB4A43AFAA85E21F07E758">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur atque sapiente beatae eum repudiandae aliquam possimus delectus veritatis numquam sit eaque esse quos ipsa, pariatur omnis obcaecati quibusdam dolore magnam!
</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <div class="style1 dropdown-link" style="background-color: rgb(84, 88, 90);">Worklist Emails</div>
        <div class="style2 dropdown-container" style="display: none;">
            <div class="ExternalClassA7D39E7BCBCE48A791E0F84E3631CC00">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur atque sapiente beatae eum repudiandae aliquam possimus delectus veritatis numquam sit eaque esse quos ipsa, pariatur omnis obcaecati quibusdam dolore magnam!

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and my jQuery is sth like below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('div.dropdown').each(function() {
      var $dropdown = $(this);      
      $(".dropdown-link", $dropdown).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("div.dropdown-link").css('background-image',''); //reset the background so CSS Background takes over
        $("div.dropdown-container").css('display','none');
        $("div.dropdown-link").css('background-color','#54585a');
        $("div.dropdown-link").css('border','none');
          if($("div.dropdown-container", $dropdown).css('display','none')){
              $("div.dropdown-link", $dropdown).css('background-color','#4b4e50');
              $("div.dropdown-link", $dropdown).css({'border-bottom':'1px dotted white', 'border-top':'1px dotted white'});
              $("div.dropdown-container", $dropdown).css('display','inline-block');
              $("div.dropdown-link", $dropdown).css('background-image','url("/SiteAssets/arrowdown.png")');
          }else{
              $("div.dropdown-link", $dropdown).css('background-image','url("/SiteAssets/img/arrow.png")');
              $("div.dropdown-container", $dropdown).css('display','none');
              $("div.dropdown-link", $dropdown).css('background-color','#54585a');
              $("div.dropdown-link", $dropdown).css('border', 'none');
          }
        return false;
      });
   });
});
```

Here is the jsbin: http://jsbin.com/hazaxunuwa/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not a good idea to use JavaScript for changing a lot of styles while you can do it with just css. You should only include one class on your `.dropdown` when it is active. Below is the sample code where I've moved all your styles to css:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('div.dropdown').each(function() {
      var $dropdown = $(this);
      var $dropdownLink = $dropdown.find('.dropdown-link');
       
      $dropdownLink.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var currentBlock = $(this).closest('.dropdown');
        
        if(currentBlock.hasClass('slide-active')) {
           currentBlock.removeClass('slide-active');
        } else {
           $('div.dropdown').removeClass('slide-active');
           currentBlock.addClass('slide-active');
        }
      });
   });
});
```

```css
.dropdown-link {
  background: #54585a;
}
.dropdown-container {
  display: none;
}

.slide-active .dropdown-container {
  display: block;
}

.slide-active .dropdown-link {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted white;
  background: #4b4e50;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="style1 dropdown-link">Timecard Error Message</div>
  <div class="style2 dropdown-container">
    <div class="ExternalClassA37E015771DB4A43AFAA85E21F07E758">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur atque sapiente beatae eum repudiandae aliquam possimus delectus veritatis numquam sit eaque esse quos ipsa, pariatur omnis obcaecati quibusdam dolore magnam!
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="style1 dropdown-link">Worklist Emails</div>
  <div class="style2 dropdown-container">
    <div class="ExternalClassA7D39E7BCBCE48A791E0F84E3631CC00">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur atque sapiente beatae eum repudiandae aliquam possimus delectus veritatis numquam sit eaque esse quos ipsa, pariatur omnis obcaecati quibusdam dolore magnam!

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="style1 dropdown-link">Unable to Enter a Future Timecard</div>
  <div class="style2 dropdown-container">
    <div class="ExternalClassD8605E4C12364C5685331D8368E84E8A">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur atque sapiente beatae eum repudiandae aliquam possimus delectus veritatis numquam sit eaque esse quos ipsa, pariatur omnis obcaecati quibusdam dolore magnam!

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Avoid `styling` in javascript, it would be a bad practice.

Here is the **snippet** of what you want.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('div.dropdown').each(function() {
      var $dropdown = $(this);      
      $(".dropdown-link", $dropdown).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var parent_drop = $(this).closest(".dropdown");
        if($(parent_drop).is(".open")){
          $(parent_drop).removeClass("open");
          $("div.dropdown-container").css('display','none');
        } else {
          $(parent_drop).addClass("open");
          $("div.dropdown-link").css('background-image',''); //reset the background so CSS Background takes over
        $("div.dropdown-container").css('display','none');
        $("div.dropdown-link").css('background-color','#54585a');
        $("div.dropdown-link").css('border','none');
          if($("div.dropdown-container", $dropdown).css('display','none')){
              $("div.dropdown-link", $dropdown).css('background-color','#4b4e50');
              $("div.dropdown-link", $dropdown).css({'border-bottom':'1px dotted white', 'border-top':'1px dotted white'});
              $("div.dropdown-container", $dropdown).css('display','inline-block');
              $("div.dropdown-link", $dropdown).css('background-image','url("/SiteAssets/arrowdown.png")');
          }else{
              $("div.dropdown-link", $dropdown).css('background-image','url("/SiteAssets/img/arrow.png")');
              $("div.dropdown-container", $dropdown).css('display','none');
              $("div.dropdown-link", $dropdown).css('background-color','#54585a');
              $("div.dropdown-link", $dropdown).css('border', 'none');
          }
        }
        
        
        return false;
      });
   });
});
```

```css
.style1 {
  font-family: "Segoe UI","Segoe",Tahoma,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #fff; line-height:22px; cursor: pointer; background-color:#5d6264; padding-left:3px; margin-left:5px;  
  background: url('/SiteAssets/img/gt2.png') no-repeat center left; 
  background-size:12px 12px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.style2 {
  font-family: "Segoe UI","Segoe",Tahoma,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  border-bottom:1px dotted silver;
  padding:0px 5px 5px 15px; margin-left:5px; background-color:#606567; color:#fff; display:none; 
}
.style2 a{color: white !important; text-decoration:underline !important;}

.style3{
  font-family: "Segoe UI","Segoe",Tahoma,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px; font-weight:bold; color:#fff;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
        <div class="style1 dropdown-link" style='background-color: rgb(75, 78, 80);'>Timecard Error Message</div>
        <div class="style2 dropdown-container" style="display: none">
            <div class="ExternalClassA37E015771DB4A43AFAA85E21F07E758">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur atque sapiente beatae eum repudiandae aliquam possimus delectus veritatis numquam sit eaque esse quos ipsa, pariatur omnis obcaecati quibusdam dolore magnam!
</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <div class="style1 dropdown-link" style="background-color: rgb(84, 88, 90);">Worklist Emails</div>
        <div class="style2 dropdown-container" style="display: none;">
            <div class="ExternalClassA7D39E7BCBCE48A791E0F84E3631CC00">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur atque sapiente beatae eum repudiandae aliquam possimus delectus veritatis numquam sit eaque esse quos ipsa, pariatur omnis obcaecati quibusdam dolore magnam!

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, by making use of the **`index`** value of the [**`.each()`**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) function, when the user clicks on a title, we loop through the content array and for the matching item we use [**`toggleClass()`**](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) to toggle the class `.expand` which is responsible for expanding the content section, and for each not matching item we remove this class.

[**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/udhquhgy/4/)

```js
var titles = $('.title'),
  content = $('.content');

titles.each(function(index) {
  $(this).on('click', function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < content.length; ++i) {
      if (i == index) {
        $(content[i]).toggleClass('expand');
      } else {
        $(content[i]).removeClass('expand');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.accord { width: 500px; outline: 1px solid #aaa; }
.title { color: white; background-color: #555; padding: 10px 5px; cursor: pointer; }
.content { max-height: 1px; overflow: hidden; }
.expand { max-height: 1000px; padding: 5px 5px 20px 5px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accord">
  <div class="title">This is title ONE</div>
  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus debitis, ipsum at asperiores dignissimos aperiam qui. Dignissimos mollitia incidunt commodi, necessitatibus numquam corporis, ex expedita ut consequatur maiores doloremque eius.
  </div>
  <div class="title">This is title TWO</div>
  <div class="content">Cake gummies candy canes topping donut caramels candy bear claw. Powder brownie chupa chups macaroon jelly beans chocolate chocolate jelly. Chupa chups apple pie marshmallow dessert tart apple pie cotton candy tiramisu. Fruitcake cupcake pie. Cheesecake
    bear claw croissant candy tart. Liquorice cookie candy topping macaroon.
  </div>
  <div class="title">And here's title THREE</div>
  <div class="content">Percolator, spoon half and half variety saucer caramelization qui milk. Sugar aromatic white at skinny roast redeye decaffeinated shop. Siphon spoon id, robust froth doppio redeye café au lait. So aroma, a grinder crema froth acerbic. Cultivar ristretto
    carajillo turkish galão cappuccino, roast to go black body milk. Est decaffeinated seasonal coffee robust, qui sit french press single shot single origin.
  </div>
</div>
```